# google play game services giving transparent screen

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, logcat, android-logcat

So this is my story...
I am trying to integrate leaderboards and achievements in my app. I tried a lot of times, i followed all the steps read same articles 5-6 times and new ones too.
But ALL IN VAIN. Every time i tried to sign in to google after selecting an account i will see rotating status bar and then "UNFORTUNATLY, GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES HAS STOPPED" [Report][Ok] :(
and then screen hangs,its like a completly transparent layer on my screen,i can see my buttons behind but nothing can be touched. Then i have to press the back button and then the screen of choosing account comes again.
Story doesn't end here....
I made Type a number challenge sample app properly,i added two testers and walla, ALL IZZ WELL... Then i integrated my whole project to this app and it was a walla again. :)..
I was able to access the Leaderboards and Achievements,The app works absolutly perfect as expected. But When i tried add a new tester and told others to try it went to the same problem like initial. So finally i can update and access my achievements and leaderboards with only those two tester accounts,any new tester is just giving me the transparent screen.:[

I cant  tell my problem more elaboratly. Please help me. I am attaching the error log too.

```
>>03-16 01:12:55.381: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2404): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-16 01:13:00.031: E/BatteryService(2404): Could not open /efs/FactoryApp/batt_cable_count
03-16 01:13:01.261: E/SELinux(24363): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file 
03-16 01:13:01.261: E/SELinux(24363):  
03-16 01:13:01.261: E/SELinux(24363): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-N7100_4.3_0020
03-16 01:13:01.261: E/SELinux(24363):  
03-16 01:13:01.261: E/SELinux(24363):  
03-16 01:13:01.261: E/SELinux(24363): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404): Writing exception to parcel
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13175)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2044)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:615)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:2100)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
03-16 01:13:02.536: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:03.261: E/DatabaseUtils(2404): Writing exception to parcel
03-16 01:13:03.261: E/DatabaseUtils(2404): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
03-16 01:13:03.261: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13175)
03-16 01:13:03.261: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2044)
03-16 01:13:03.261: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:615)
03-16 01:13:03.261: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
03-16 01:13:03.261: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
03-16 01:13:03.261: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
03-16 01:13:03.261: E/DatabaseUtils(2404):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:03.406: E/SELinux(24378): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file 
03-16 01:13:03.406: E/SELinux(24378):  
03-16 01:13:03.406: E/SELinux(24378): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-N7100_4.3_0020
03-16 01:13:03.406: E/SELinux(24378):  
03-16 01:13:03.406: E/SELinux(24378):  
03-16 01:13:03.406: E/SELinux(24378): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
03-16 01:13:03.446: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2404): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-16 01:13:07.631: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2404): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.PACLConfig
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.PACLConfig
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3784)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:5008)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3423)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3315)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:258)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2122)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/auth/firstparty/shared/PACLConfig
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     ... 19 more
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.PACLConfig" on path: .
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-16 01:13:07.656: E/Parcel(2404):     ... 19 more
03-16 01:13:07.936: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2404): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.common.acl.ScopeData
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.acl.ScopeData
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2264)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1661)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1992)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3784)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:5008)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3205)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3123)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:157)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2122)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/common/acl/ScopeData
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     ... 21 more
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.acl.ScopeData" on path: .
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-16 01:13:09.911: E/Parcel(2404):     ... 21 more
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.login.GrantCredentialsWithAclActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.login.CircleImageView.a(SourceFile:80)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at aro.a(SourceFile:109)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b(SourceFile:1500)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at v.a(SourceFile:938)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at v.a(SourceFile:1115)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at g.run(SourceFile:682)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at v.f(SourceFile:1478)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at n.onStart(SourceFile:570)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1188)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5382)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2279)
03-16 01:13:10.116: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    ... 11 more
03-16 01:13:10.431: E/android.os.Debug(2404): !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
03-16 01:13:16.616: E/Watchdog(2404): !@Sync 2721
03-16 01:13:19.431: E/InputDispatcher(2404): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-16 01:13:19.431: E/InputDispatcher(2404): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-16 01:13:19.431: E/InputDispatcher(2404): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-16 01:13:19.511: E/ViewRootImpl(2404): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-16 01:13:19.546: E/SELinux(24452): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file 
03-16 01:13:19.546: E/SELinux(24452):  
03-16 01:13:19.551: E/SELinux(24452): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-N7100_4.3_0020
03-16 01:13:19.551: E/SELinux(24452):  
03-16 01:13:19.551: E/SELinux(24452):  
03-16 01:13:19.551: E/SELinux(24452): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
03-16 01:13:20.551: E/(24452): Device driver API match
03-16 01:13:20.551: E/(24452): Device driver API version: 23
03-16 01:13:20.551: E/(24452): User space API version: 23 
03-16 01:13:20.551: E/(24452): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Nov 29 14:18:37 KST 2013 
03-16 01:13:20.676: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2404): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
03-16 01:13:45.026: E/BatteryService(2404): Could not open /efs/FactoryApp/batt_cable_count
03-16 01:13:46.621: E/Watchdog(2404): !@Sync 2722
03-16 01:14:16.621: E/Watchdog(2404): !@Sync 2723
03-16 01:14:17.986: E/SPPClientService(19217): [b] sendPingReq
03-16 01:14:18.041: E/SELinux(24508): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file 
03-16 01:14:18.041: E/SELinux(24508):  
03-16 01:14:18.041: E/SELinux(24508): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-N7100_4.3_0020
03-16 01:14:18.041: E/SELinux(24508):  
03-16 01:14:18.041: E/SELinux(24508):  
03-16 01:14:18.041: E/SELinux(24508): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
03-16 01:14:18.151: E/SPPClientService(24508): ============PushLog. commonIsShipBuild. stop!
03-16 01:14:18.151: E/SPPClientService(24508): [PushClientApplication] Push log off : This is Ship build version
03-16 01:14:19.031: E/SPPClientService(19217): [b] __PingReply__
03-16 01:14:22.181: E/BatteryService(2404): Could not open /efs/FactoryApp/batt_cable_count
03-16 01:14:32.491: E/SELinux(24535): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file 
03-16 01:14:32.491: E/SELinux(24535):  
03-16 01:14:32.491: E/SELinux(24535): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-N7100_4.3_0020
03-16 01:14:32.491: E/SELinux(24535):  
03-16 01:14:32.491: E/SELinux(24535):  
03-16 01:14:32.491: E/SELinux(24535): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
03-16 01:14:32.686: E/ParseService(24535): onStartCommand() - return START_STICKY
03-16 01:14:40.601: E/SELinux(24552): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file 
03-16 01:14:40.601: E/SELinux(24552):  
03-16 01:14:40.601: E/SELinux(24552): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-N7100_4.3_0020
03-16 01:14:40.601: E/SELinux(24552):  
03-16 01:14:40.601: E/SELinux(24552):  
03-16 01:14:40.601: E/SELinux(24552): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
03-16 01:14:46.621: E/Watchdog(2404): !@Sync 2724
03-16 01:14:54.126: E/GCM(3021): Dropping message from null
03-16 01:15:00.046: E/BatteryService(2404): Could not open /efs/FactoryApp/batt_cable_count
03-16 01:15:16.621: E/Watchdog(2404): !@Sync 2725
```

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: samsung galaxy note 2. Device is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be due to stricter permissions checking on Android 4+ physical devices than is the case for 4+ emulator devices e.g.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australian-technology/beware-stricter-manifest-checking-in-android-ics/#.

I suggest you look first at your Manifest file.